# Find the entry in the class

Tags: jquery

I have elements in my document with these kind of classes:

```
<div class="field field-type-number-integer field-field-ocenka1">
<div class="field field-type-number-integer field-field-ocenka2">
```

How to do a search on the basis of whether the occurrence of a certain class (ocenka). And to add to his class.

Comment: What? Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find elements by particla class names you should use [jQuery "Attribute Contains Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)":

```
$('[class*="ocenka"]'
```

This code finds all elements with class names that contain `ocenka`.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/SfeKr/

Comment: $('div[class*="ocenka"]').addClass("ocenka");
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
$('div[class*="ocenka"]').addClass("some-new-class");
```

### And a [JSFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/YLLAc/).

Don't forget to learn about [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) that will help you in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

This will get all `div` elements with a class of `field-field-ocenkaN` where `N` is a number.

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return this.className.match(/\bfield-field-ocenka\d+\b/);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FH2t9/).

You can add a new class to these matched elements with [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).